# php + mysql вывод даты в другом формате

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно сделать вывод даты из `mysql` в нужном мне формате, ни для кого не секрет что дата хранится в типе `date` как `гггг-мм-дд`,

мне нужно конвертировать в `дд.мм.гггг`,

при этом не при самом `SELECT`'e, т.е. когда выборка по `*` и не в цикле перебирать все элементы и конвертировать дату, 
возможно ли так?

Может есть какая-то предустановка, как например кодировку задавать через `SET NAMES` ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

**в MySQL нельзя изменить формат по-умолчанию `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`**

но вы можете сделать это с помоьюш дополнительных функций как

```
DATE_FORMAT( datecol , '%d.%m.%Y')  AS datecol

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dateColumn FROM table
```

[документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: В MySQL **можно** изменить формат вывода даты. Собственно вы неплохо описали как это сделать. Наверное, вы все-таки имели в виду "_изменить формат вывода даты по-умолчанию_" или что-то еще.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да спасибо за заметку, формат по умолчанию без доп. функций нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая, что вопрос задан по MySQL + PHP, скорее всего форматирование даты нужно именно для PHP.

Давайте разберемся.
MySQL - это слой данных, т.е. модель.
А форматирование данных для пользователя - это уже вопрос отображения, т.е. представление.

Отсюда значит, что вопрос подразумевает смешивание слоев модели и представления прямо в модели. И не просто в модели, а прямо средствами СУБД. А это в корне не правильный подход и принесет в будущем разработчику массу проблем. Например, завтра разработчику нужно будет сделать разное форматирование даты для разных языков интерфейса, а также произоводить с датой некие вычисления. Мне не представляется простой путь, как это сделать?

Поэтому мне не вполне понятно, почему заминусовали предыдущий ответ. Т.к. он предлагает более правильный путь:

`(new DateTime($mySqlResult['createdAt']))->format('d.m.Y');`

или лучше

`(new \IntlDateFormatter('ru_RU', \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE))->format(new \DateTime($mySqlResult['createdAt'])));`

Comment: Вроде точно написано что нужно из Mysql

Answer (score 2):

Я сделал так, при выводе даты, в цикле вставил строку:

```
<?=date("d.m.y",strtotime($sp['date']))?>
```

где `date` это столбец таблицы

Answer (score 1):

на php можно это сделать `date("D.m.Y",strtotime($datetime))`

Answer (score -1):

Если кому поможет я сделал так:

Есть таблица (`table_name`) с датами рождения (`birth_date`).

В таблице дата имеет вид `2006-05-23`.
Существует очень полезная функция `CONCAT()`, которая собирает любые данные в строку, а также мои любимые функции для работы с датой `DAY(), MONTH(), YEAR()`.

Теперь запрос:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DAY(birth_date),".",MONTH(birth_date),".",YEAR(birth_date)) as NewDate FROM table_name
```

На выходе получим:

```
| NewDate |
| 23.05.2006 |
```

Причём `NewDate` - это уже строка, которую мы легко выведем на экран с помощью PHP:

```
?php

//соединяемся с MySQL с помощью 
mysql_connect('ваши параметры'); 

//выбираем базу данных
mysql_select_db('ваша база данных');

//создаём запрос
$sql=sprintf("SELECT 

CONCAT(DAY(birth_date),'.',MONTH(birth_date),'.',YEAR(birth_date)) as NewDate FROM table_name");

//выполняем запрос
$r=mysql_query($sql);

//если запрос выполнен успешно

if ($r) {

//запускаем цикл, в котором переменной $row присваиваем значения полученного запроса

         while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {

             // выводим поле "NewDate" на экран
                 echo "<p>Дата в нужном формате: {$row['NewDate']}</p><br />";
              };

} else {

         //если что-то пошло не так выводим сообщение об ошибке
         echo "<p>Ошибка" . mysql_error() . "</p>";

};

?
```

Получаем на выходе столбик с датами в нужном нам формате:

Дата в нужном формате: 23.05.2006

Дата в нужном формате: 25.03.2005

Дата в нужном формате: 04.12.2002

Дата в нужном формате: 15.12.2000

.....

.....

Comment: Это никому не поможет. Рекомендую прочесть правильный ответ выше.